# Can collapsed cells in jupyter lab display name/label

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've started using jupyter lab to develop a project I'm working on. To reduce clutter I collapse cells, but the only indicator of what's in the cell is a dot,dot,dot graphic. Is there any way to replace the dots with a descriptive label?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing [Codefolding extension](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/codefolding/readme.html)

It appears to achieve what you need:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks perfect, except (from the docs): "Most nbextensions here should work fine ... ... but won’t work with jupyterlab..."

Comment: @d8sconz looks like a feature that is not yet available, you can support the idea in github issue https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4083